# Meaning of "Provision of Collateral"

Tags: banking, terminology

When I reading about bank processing, I encountered some difficulties. I want to know the meaning of "provision of collateral".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collateral means something of value that one needs to keep with Bank if one needs any loan.
For example if you are taking a loan of 100,000 you may need to keep something [pledge shares, house, CD's or any other thing which the Bank may think is of value]

Comment: +1 As a minor addition to Dheer's list, _automobiles_ are often pledged for loans, in fact, purchased using loans, and the lender often keeps the _title document_ which shows the purchaser as the owner with the lender holding a lien on it. Even if the original purchaser has physical possession of the title document, he cannot sell the car (or use it to get another loan!) because of the lien recorded on the title unless the lien-holder is notified and the lien paid off.